# Gradle implementations not working with JavaFX

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, guava

I am trying to do some fun Java projects on the side to get better at coding. Currently, I'm trying to do an offline, local password manager with JavaFX and Gradle.

I wanted a way to hash a password, for security, and then store it in a file. Previously, I used [Google's Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) in an Android App because it had some good hashing capabilities, so I thought I would use it in this project too. Unfortunately, I can't access any of Guava's APIs/objects.

This is my `settings.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.10'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.24.1'
}

group 'me.tisleo'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.8.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'me.tisleo.jpasswordmanager'
    mainClass = 'me.tisleo.jpasswordmanager.JPasswordManager'
}

javafx {
    version = '18-ea+6'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.0')
    implementation('org.kordamp.bootstrapfx:bootstrapfx-core:0.4.0')
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

The guava documentation simply said to add the implementation `implementation("com.google.guava:guava:31.1-jre")` to my `settings.gradle` file, so I did. Whenever I try to use the library, for e.g. using the `Hashing` class, which would look something like `Hashing.sha256().hashString(myString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`, IntelliJ says
"Cannot resolve symbol 'Hashing'".

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've made sure to reload Gradle, and even tried manually adding the Guava files to my Project Structure.

Comment: Do you have a module info? If so does it require guava?

Comment: Unless you are using a guava for something else, I recommend using the inbuilt [jdk hash facilities](https://www.baeldung.com/sha-256-hashing-java) instead of an external library.

Comment: @jewelsea My module info didn't require guava, so I added it, but now it says "module not found". Also, I was only looking to use Guava for hashing, although it provides a range of core libs which I was interested in. Anyway, I'll definitely check out the inbuilt facilities. I'm slightly concerned if I want to use other libraries and them not working - I'm assuming the module info might fix this? Thanks!

Comment: How did you ask idea to create your project?  Did you use the [new JavaFX project wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html)? If you did it created a module info and you must maintain or remove it if you want to modify libraries.  No you don’t need it.  But if you don’t have it you will have a more complicated runtime environment. To understand more study Java modules and the modular and non modular documentation at openjfx.io.

Comment: @jewelsea thanks for the heads up (I managed to find the module info class) but like I stated above it wasn't working. I found out that I needed to require "com.google.common" instead of guava. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, not sure I would've found out the fix.

Comment: Unfortunately [guava currently doesn’t have a module-info](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/2970).  It does have automatic module info in the jar manifest and you need to use that name, which I guess is `com.google.common`, because that name worked for you. [`jdeps`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/man/jdeps.html) can tell you the module name or you can look at the module info or manifest in the jar or use the jar name if the module isn’t defined in those places.

Comment: Google should document their library usage better and provide module info in their jars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have modular project, so you need to include the following line in your `module-info.java` file to access the guava API:

```
requires com.google.common;
```

With current guava distributions (31.1-jre), this module name is defined inside the jar file in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file via the line:

```
Automatic-Module-Name: com.google.common
```